# Lining numbers in Math and OsF in text - ArnoPro font - using XeLaTeX

Tags: osf

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[]{fontspec}%
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Mapping=tex-text,Path = ./Fonts/ArnoPro/ ,Numbers=OldStyle,
UprightFont= ArnoPro-Regular.otf,
BoldFont= ArnoPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont= ArnoPro-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont= ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf,
]{ArnoPro}%
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}%

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"30}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"31}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"32}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"33}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"34}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"35}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"36}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"37}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"38}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"39}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

1234567890

$1234567890$


\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

But I need the output should be as `OsF` format in text and `Lining` numbers in `Math`, I've tried with

```
\everymath{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}}%
```

But nothing happened, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Arno Pro, so I do it with a different font. Just remove `%` from the commented options.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% replace GaramondLibre with ArnoPro
\setmainfont{GaramondLibre}[
  %Path = ./Fonts/ArnoPro/,
  Extension=.otf,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]
\newfontfamily{\arnoprolining}{GaramondLibre}[
  %Path = ./Fonts/ArnoPro/,
  Extension=.otf,
  Ligatures=TeX,
  %Numbers=Lining,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  NFSSFamily=apl,
]

\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{apl}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{apl}{b}{n}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"30}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"31}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"32}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"33}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"34}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"35}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"36}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"37}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"38}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"39}%
}

\begin{document}

1234567890 $1234567890$ {\boldmath$01234567890$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need `mathastext` (at least for the numbers). Also be aware that `Ligatures=TeX` and `Mapping=tex-text` are the same, but the latter is invalid with LuaLaTeX. However it's not needed, because it's on by default when `\setmainfont` is processed.

For “strange” reasons, you need to load `mathastext` after `\setmainfont`. I believe this is a misfeature.

Comment: sir @egreg; Your suggestion works as champion

Comment: I used `mathastext` package is for getting `alphabets` also in `ArnoPro` font in `Math`, otherwise, `Math alphabets` came in `CM` family, is there any better way available? Sorry, if my question is silly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your code that should achieve the desired output:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{ArnoPro}

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\MTsetmathskips{true}
\MTversion[lcg]{varnormal}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"30}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"31}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"32}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"33}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"34}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"35}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"36}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"37}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"38}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{numbers}{"39}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

1234567890

$1234567890$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, received error message as `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \MTversion[l
                 cg]{varnormal}
? x
`

Comment: I'm using `MikTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.3)` in `Windows10`