Change number style with mathastext
I'm using a commercial font (Fleischman BT Pro) which contains different types of numbers (old style proportional and tabular).
This font does not contain a math font, why I'm using the package mathastext. But unfortunately this package is not using the tabular numbers which are selected for the document.
Is there a solution to fix this?
I need tabular numbers for my math mode and for my tables. The image shows in the first line the output for regular text and the second line for inline math.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz}
\usepackage{luaotfload} 

\setmainfont{Fleischman BT Pro}[%
    Numbers={Tabular},%
]

\usepackage[%
    italic,%
    defaultmathsizes,%
    %subdued,%
    asterisk,%
]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
1234567890

$1234567890$
\end{document}


I think I can reproduce with a freely available font: with \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Numbers={OldStyle}] the text setting is also not used in math. This is the reverse behavior (old style in text, lining in math) but I guess it is the same issue that the settings are not applied.

Yes, here is the related post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444565/mathastext-wrong-digits-in-math-mode
But there is also a comment that it was fixed in version 1.3t. But I did not test it with that font

@Marijn I tried with your choice of font and using xelatex (commenting out luaotfload) and the output is fine: old style both in text and math.

The  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444565/mathastext-wrong-digits-in-math-mode link mentions a mathastext 1.3s change, looking in mathastext documentation for that entry in change log I found nearby the 1.3o entry This fixes issues with for example old style figures being used while the text font used lining figures (or vice versa, depending on the font.  Searching in the code comments for luaotfload there is a whole section on page 87 with a comment Not all is resolved, as I comment online at https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/204#issuecomment-216465680.

It seems the matter relates to a rather deep incompatibility of mathastext with lualatex.  Any chance you can switch to xelatex?  Or rather drop mathastext and use unicode-math rather?

Do your really need \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz}? Isn't it default with current lualatex?  If I drop this line and use the @Marijn font both text and math mode look alike.

Comparing the logs with/without \defaultfontfeatures line I see (fontspec)             <->"name:TeXGyreTermes:mode=harf;script=latn;language=df  versus (fontspec)             <->"name:TeXGyreTermes:mode=node;script=latn;language=df.  I think from the comments (which I do not understand) in mathastext.pdf that a core update of mathastext is required to recognize mode=harf in the font name.  It looks as if it recognizes only mode=node. Will you ping author or I do?

I checked it on my side and I can confirm all your findings. If I remove the \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz} or replace it by \defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic}, then it works. If it's okay for you, please ping the author directly, because you have the better understanding of this topic. But anyhow: Thank you very much for your perfect answer!

@Dieter I have pinged the mathastext author by email about this issue...

@Dieter my texlive manager got a new mathastext this week (1.4a) and the change log says it fixed a lualatex harfbuzz issue so maybe you could try updating and see what happens.

@user691586: Sounds great. Is it automatically available or do I need to install it manually?

@Dieter the CTAN page says it is available on MikTeX and TeXLive.  I don't know about MikTeX but with TeXLive you need to do tlmgr update mathastext, or if you are on macOS, and use MacTeX, use the TeXLiveUtility app.  Only the general process here to update packages on your installation... I hope I do not send you on some treacherous path... I heard something about MikTeX automatically fetching packages, but I have never tested this. I don't know how it works.

@Dieter wait, from CTAN you can go to the package home page and there is direct link there to download the .sty file, which you can then put inside your project repertory for testing.

@user691586: I updated MikTeX, but now I'm getting an error message when I'm using HarfBuzz. Even w/o mathastext or any other package. I just started a new question for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723297/error-message-with-renderer-harfbuzz

@Dieter very sorry to have motivated you to update which got you into trouble...

@user691586: Don't worry, updating is normally a good idea and after solving the issue with Ulrike's solution it works now. But I'm facing still the issue from my original question in this post. So, no improvement. but I can live not using HarfBuzz

@Dieter Is this problem solved? I have a solution for this.

@MadyYuvi: Sorry for the late answer. No, the problem is not finally solved, but I have a workaround. But please share your solution.

This solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694838/lining-numbers-in-math-and-osf-in-text-arnopro-font-using-xelatex will helps you
