Error message with Renderer=HarfBuzz
I just run a MikTeX update to get the latest version for all my packages and now I'm getting an error message when using my font Fleischman BT Pro with the option HarfBuzz.
Error message: error: 10: Font \TU/FleischmanBTPro(0)/m/it/10=name:Fleischman not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \end{document}
MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz}
\setmainfont{Fleischman BT Pro}

\begin{document}
Test 1234567890
\end{document}

What I can see in the related log-file:
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.


LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FleischmanBTPro(0)/m/sl' in size <10> not av
ailable
(Font)              Font shape `TU/FleischmanBTPro(0)/m/it' tried instead on in
put line 10.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "Fleisch
man" not found.
! Font \TU/FleischmanBTPro(0)/m/it/10=name:Fleischman not loadable: metric data 
not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
B
l.10 \end{document}
                 
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

[1{C:/Users/Diete/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}


Does this problem occur with any other otf fonts and/or with a different renderer choice, or just with the combination of Fleischman BT Pro and HarfBuzz?

Try without the spaces in the font name.  See also https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/285

I can reproduce with TeXLive and TeX Gyre Termes but issue disappears with TeXGyreTermes as suggested by @UlrikeFischer.

Yes, the error disappears when I remove the spaces. Thank you, @UlrikeFischer
